# how to save soap request and response in DB automatically using Java?

Tags: java, database, soap

how to save soap request and response  in DB automatically using Java? I need some guide of how doing that. I know that I have to use Axis to capture the SOAP messages but how to save them in the DB?

Comment: The request and response, how do you want to store this in DB?

Comment: I want to store it as a string in DB

Comment: And what binding method have you used?

Comment: i used servlet filter. but i do not know how to create a client application to contact with uddi?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [spring-integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration) to join together the xml flows as pipelines. It'll also help with the soap ports.